# Which version of .net need to be installed (WPF ,Prism7) on the PC?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, prism

I wrote a Prism7  WPF app with Visual Studio 2019.

I created the project with Prism Blank App template and selected newest version I can see(.net framework 4.7.2).

My PC is Win10 1809 and .net 4.7.2 is installed as default.
But my app is required to run in PC of Win10 1709 which .net 4.7.1 is installed as default.

Question

1. Do the users have to install .net 4.7.2 before running the app?
   (PC of the users can not access the internet and I prepared the offline installer of .net 4.7.2)
2. As the app is simple, can I rewrite the app in a lower version like .net 4.6.1 to resolve the version problem? (create a project with .net 4.6.1 and copy all the code into it)

Comment: For today you are supposed to be on .NET Core 3.0 with WPF, and .NET Framework version no longer matters.

Comment: @LexLi thanks for comment. I tried to use the Prism framework and I think it does not support .net Core3.0 because I can not select core 3.0 when I create the project with the prism blank project app template. And my app only runs in Windows PC, so cross platform does not matter.Do you mean I am using Core 3.0 even though I selected .net framework 4.7.2 with WPF.

Comment: Do not "rewrite the app", simply change the target version.  Project > Properties > Application tab, "Target framework" setting.  Flip a coin to decide between 4.7.1 and 4.6.1

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the comment.It helps a lot. I changed the version to 4.6.1 and it works by debug though other issue still suffers([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59045810/files-in-visual-studio-debug-folder-and-the-generated-installer-include-differen)).Can I say that my 4.6.1 app can work in PC which has higher version than 4.6.1 of .net ? I just want to know the basic rule.

Comment: You don't really need to use its template to create a new Prism 7 project. Use the .NET Core WPF template, and then add the relevant NuGet packages from https://www.nuget.org/packages/Prism.Core/

Comment: @LexLi Thanks! It does have a Core version  template. But it said it is not a official release and need to use MyGet, so I chose the .Net framework template.  Maybe the Core one is right for today. But I have step in the test stage and the app works. So I only want to know what should be prepared when I give this app to the user and how to make this app work in user's PC most easily. Rewrite and retest takes too much time and I will use Core next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a new Prism.Wpf app with the Prism Template Pack, the Dialog actually gives you a dropdown of available Framework Options. The default is 4.7.2, however if you look at NuGet.org you'll actually notice that the Prism.Wpf package actually targets .NET Framework 4.5. This means that it remains fully compatible for those who are working on legacy applications and who can't update from 4.5, as well as those developers who may just be starting out development and want to take advantage of 4.7.2, or 4.8. Of course you are equally able to develop with any framework version in between.

[image: Configure your new project dialog]

In short, you're free to develop your Prism.Wpf application with any version of the .NET Framework for which you have a proper SDK installed on your machine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and Prism!  Now I know I can use Prism when I have .NET version >= 4.5 in general. But I am new to .NET, so I am still not sure about if I have to install a new version(app's build version) of .NET to run my app.Can you please answer the question in my case? Users' PC is .NET 4.7.1. Can I rebuild the app by .NET 4.6.1 to avoid the .NET install before running the app?