# Files in Visual studio debug folder and the generated installer include different dll file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I wrote a WPF app in Visual Studio 2019 and works in debug mode.

But when I created a installer with "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects" Extension,
the app created by the installer does not work.

In the project to create the installer, I only added the primary output of my WPF project to "Application Folder".

I compared the debug folder of my Visual Studio and the folder created by the installer,
the dll files in the folders are different.

1. pdb files are removed.
2. dlls(netstandard.dll,System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll,System.IO.Compression.dll,System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll,System.Net.Http.dll) ares added.
3. dlls(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll,System.ValueTuple.dll) are different.

difference of System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll is below

- the one works: 16760 bytes  PE Header->Flags: DLL, Handles 32 bit
  words, Executable
- the one does not work: 16248 bytes  PE
  Header->Flags: DLL, Handles addresses larger than 2 GB, Executable

Question

1. As I said, I only added the output of the project to the directory of installer project,
   what causes the difference 2 and 3?
2. I replaced the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll of installer with the one in my debug folder,
   and it works.So I removed this dll in "Detected Dependencies" and add the one in debug folder into the "Application Folder" of the installer project.Rebuild and the installer works too.But I want a proper way to fix this problem.

Comment: Just as an idea, you should not compare the debug build with the installed software but the release build. I can imagine that some of the DLLs that are different were also in debug mode and therefore a bit different than when you installed it.

Comment: @Joelius thanks for comment. I am beginner with .Net. I dont know clearly about the difference of debug and release folder in Visual Studio. I compared them and the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll is the same. Only my exe file and its pdb is different. So the release build's dll is also different with installed one's dll. By the way System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll is a dll my code reference to, I think it should be the same in the three folder talked above.